# Reack-native-voice pick up the voice from react-native-tts

Tags: react-native, react-native-voice

I am trying to use react-native-voice/voice to convert speech to text, then on the server I translate the text and the server returns me the translated text which I play back using react-native-tts.  The problem is that react-native-voice/voice picks up the voice from react-native-tts from the speaker (even at a low volume) and translates it back into text, so the person who speaks hears himself.
Maybe someone has encountered this and knows how to solve it?

I tried to use WebRTC, but it is not suitable for me, as I plan to make a conference call (up to 7 people).